# Can we draw things on any Swing GUI component?

Tags: java, swing

Can we draw things on any Swing GUI component? If yes then Why should we use a panel as
a canvas for drawings rather than a label or a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Perfoming Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for details about how painting is done in Swing

The second part of your question depends on what it is you want to achieve.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't paint directly onto existing components because painting is actually done by the UI delegate. If you want to change the look and feel of these components, you should consider creating a custom UI delegate to perform the painting as you need. This ensures that the painting is done correctly.

This doesn't stop you from overriding its `paintComponent` method, but with complex controls like buttons, lists, tables and trees, you may find it difficult to achieve the results you want.

Equally, tables, trees and lists use renderers to provide customised output

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume a label is a price tag and a panel is a piece of paper. Do you usually `paint()` on buttons and price tags in real life? :)

Answer (score 0):

Labels and Buttons have a lot of extra "features" and capabilities that will probably get in your way or bite you with bugs.  JPanel is, almost literally, a clean slate on which to start.